# Cannot parse multiple statements at once in lark parser python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a programming language with lark, and am trying to figure out how to parse multi line code. I'm getting the following error whenever I parse

```
print("HI");
print("HI");
```

Error:

```py
PS E:\ParserAndLexer> & C:/Python38/python.exe e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\lexer.py", line 416, in lex
    for x in l.lex(stream, self.root_lexer.newline_types, self.root_lexer.ignore_types):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\lexer.py", line 200, in lex
    raise UnexpectedCharacters(stream, line_ctr.char_pos, line_ctr.line, line_ctr.column, allowed=allowed, state=self.state, token_history=last_token and [last_token])
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal defined for 'p' at line 2 col 1

print("HI");
^

Expecting: {'RBRACE'}

Previous tokens: Token('SEMICOLON', ';')


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(lite_parser(lite_code))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\lark.py", line 464, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(text, start=start)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parser_frontends.py", line 148, in parse
    return self._parse(token_stream, start, set_parser_state)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parser_frontends.py", line 63, in _parse
    return self.parser.parse(input, start, *args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 35, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(*args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 86, in parse
    for token in stream:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\indenter.py", line 32, in _process
    for token in stream:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\lexer.py", line 431, in lex
    raise UnexpectedToken(t, e.allowed, state=e.state)
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedToken: Unexpected token Token('NAME', 'print') at line 2, column 1.
Expected one of:
        * RBRACE
```

Heres my `.lark` file:

```
?start: expr
      | statement
      | var
      | bool
      | condition
      | if
      | _NL* tree

?expr: STRING            -> string
     | NUMBER            -> number
     | NUMBER "+" NUMBER -> add
     | NUMBER "-" NUMBER -> sub
     | NUMBER "*" NUMBER -> mul
     | NUMBER "/" NUMBER -> div
     | STRING "+" STRING -> str_add
     | NAME              -> get_var

?bool: TRUE              -> true
     | FALSE             -> false

?var: NAME "=" expr      -> assign_var

?condition: expr "==" bool -> bool_comparison
          | expr "==" expr -> expr_comparison

?statement: "print" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> print_statement
          | "input" "(" expr ")" ";"  -> input_statement

?if : "if" condition "{" statement "}" -> if_statement

tree: _NL [_INDENT tree+ _DEDENT]


TRUE: "true"
FALSE: "false"

_NL: /(\r?\n[\t ]*)+/

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING 
%import common.NUMBER
%import common.CNAME -> NAME
%declare _INDENT _DEDENT
%import common.WS_INLINE
%ignore WS_INLINE
%ignore _NL
```

I'm ignoring newline tokens, so I don't know why this error is popping up, my full code is on github: https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How does your grammar allow a sequence of `statement`? The syntax error is the start of the second print statement - you probably need `start` to match a sequence of the things it currently matches one of.

Comment: Just as a test make `start` match `statement+` and that should work for this simple example.

Comment: Wait, I already have `statement` in start

Comment: Yes statement _singular_. So your parser matches the first print, then errors after it, at the start of the second print. Make the lines different - HI and HO - and you’ll see.

Comment: If you need any more help or ask future questions you must make the code in your question a [mre] so anyone can run exactly what you’re running and see the same result.